# Having trouble discretizing a set of coupled ODE's

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

[image: PICTURE OF EQUATIONS]

---

I'm having some trouble trying to discretize the following system of ODE's:

$$\begin{aligned} \frac{dP_1}{dz} &= -\alpha_1P_1 - \gamma_{12} P_1 P_2\\ \frac{dP_2}{dz} &= -\alpha_2P_2 + \gamma_{12} P_1 P_2\end{aligned}$$

I am able to use a centered difference Euler's method on the differential part of both equations. As follows:

$$ \frac{P_1^{i+1}-2P_1^{i}+P_1^{i-1}}{\Delta x} = - \alpha_1 P_1^i - \gamma_{12} P_1^iP_2^i $$

However, I am unsure of what to do with the product part $P_1P_2$?

This is what I have so far..

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{-1}{\Delta x} & 0\\
0 & \frac{-1}{\Delta x}
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
P_{1_(i-1)}\\
P_{2_(i-1)}
\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{2}{\Delta x} & \gamma_{12}P_2\\
.. & ..
\end{bmatrix} ...
$$

As you can see in the above matrix (where i've filled with dots) I can't have the $P_2$ term, but I have no way of factoring it out either.

If anyone could give me some advice on how to solve these coupled ODE's it would be much appreciated!

Comment: This is not a PDE but two coupled nonlinear ODEs.

Comment: thanks for letting me know. I'll be sure to edit the title. Sorry for the mistake

Comment: Once discretized, what are the unknowns of your problem? What you have done so far does not seem to be useful. You should isolate the known values from the unknown ones and then establish a set of equations to be solved in the unknown quantities. Your finite difference scheme is wrong and $z$ becomes $x$, why?

Comment: Hey, it's all supposed to with the x variable; the z was a mistake. I've edited the post and attached a picture. I can successfully isolate the variables and discretize it, however if you look at the very last line of my picture, I'm confused because in the matrix I still have P_A_i. I am eventually going to code this so I need the matrix to just contain constants. That is my issue

Comment: I think you can remove the image. Rewrite the post in terms of $x$ and properly discretize $dP/dx$... then the rest will follow. For now, everything is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If you consider a basic forward Euler discretization of your differential operator, then you have $P(x^i)\approx P^i$ and
  $$\frac{dP}{dx}(x^i)\approx \frac{P^{i+1}-P^i}{\Delta x}$$
  where $\Delta x$ is the discretization step. Used in the proposed ODE yields:
  $$\begin{aligned} \frac{P_1^{i+1}-P_1^{i}}{\Delta x} &= -\alpha_1P_1^i - \gamma_{12} P_1^i P_2^i\\ \frac{P_2^{i+1}-P_2^{i}}{\Delta x} &= -\alpha_2P_2^i + \gamma_{12} P_1^iP_2^i\end{aligned}$$
  that is
  $$\begin{aligned}
  P_1^{i+1}&= -\Delta x(\alpha_1P_1^i +\gamma_{12} P_1^i P_2^i)+P_1^{i}\\
  P_2^{i+1} &= -\Delta x(\alpha_2P_2^i - \gamma_{12} P_1^iP_2^i)+P_2^{i}\end{aligned}$$
  Knowing the values at index $i$ straightforwardly leads to the values at index $i+1$.
- If you consider a basic backward Euler discretization of your differential operator, then you have $P(x^i)\approx P^i$ and
  $$\frac{dP}{dx}(x^i)\approx \frac{P^{i}-P^{i-1}}{\Delta x}$$
  Used in the proposed ODE yields:
  $$\begin{aligned} \frac{P_1^{i}-P_1^{i-1}}{\Delta x} &= -\alpha_1P_1^i - \gamma_{12} P_1^i P_2^i\\ \frac{P_2^{i}-P_2^{i-1}}{\Delta x} &= -\alpha_2P_2^i + \gamma_{12} P_1^iP_2^i\end{aligned}$$
  that is
  $$\begin{aligned}
  P_1^{i}+\Delta x(\alpha_1P_1^i +\gamma_{12} P_1^i P_2^i)=P_1^{i-1}\\
  P_2^{i}+\Delta x(\alpha_2P_2^i - \gamma_{12} P_1^iP_2^i)=P_2^{i-1}\end{aligned}$$
  Knowing the values at index $i-1$, you have to solve a system of nonlinear equations in terms of the values at index $i$, ie something in the form $f(x)=0$.

Comment: Wow! thank you so much, this explanation was amazing